# Write to Amazon S3 bucket and Amazon RDS withinin a transaction

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

I am writing a Web Service using ASP .NET Core 3.0 and C#. This service will be used to upload a file, and the file needs to be physically stored on Amazon S3 bucket and its information also needs to be stored in AWS RDS.

I want this to be TRANSACTIONAL, meaning if either one fails, the other should be rolled back.

Can somebody help me how can I do this?

Comment: You can't! You cannot just combine two arbitrary services and make them transactional. You can however just upload the file, wait for the upload to finish, then insert a record into the db and if it fails delete the file in S3 again. You can get a little bit more sophisticated than that but you will not get it to be really transactional.

Comment: like @luk2302 said, no way to do transactional across services. But there is a way to triggering event from s3 to Lambda function. For example, once we upload a file to S3 that will fire an event to lambda then leave the rest to lambda with RDS

Comment: @Mahdi thank you for guiding, can you share an example or a link to some example?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with C#, but generally the steps will be the same

[Configure Amazon S3 to publish events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#with-s3-example-configure-event-source)

The full example below :

[Using Lambda Function with Amazon S3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_using_lambda_function_with_amazon_s3.htm)

[How to Execute Lambda Functions on S3 Event Triggers](https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers)

Once you succeed on getting s3 event on your lambda function, you will get the S3 object info. There you go, you will connect your RDS DB (e.g MySQL) with lambda to put the info finally. I found this one for C# [Connecting to an RDS Database with Lambda](https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2019/02/06/connecting-to-an-rds-database-with-lambda/)